# log4j 1.2 configuration issue with Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I am stuck. I have a configuration issue in setting up log4j with Spring MVC. Getting the below error.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Here is my controller code

```
     public class HelloWorldController {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);

int first_no=10;
int second_no=10;
int summation;
@RequestMapping("/helloworld")
   public String helloWord(ModelMap modelview){

    summation=first_no+second_no;

    System.out.println("Inside hello world");


    logger.info("Hello, World!");
      modelview.addAttribute("message", summation);

         return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

Here is my log4j.properties file

```
    # Direct log messages to stdout
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

   # Root logger option
   log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

I have kept the file under src/resources in eclipse. Can anyone help me out with this? I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably *log4j.properties* file is not in the classpath.Move the log4j.properties in *src* folder in Eclipse and under *WEB-INF/classes* when deployed in the Container.

Comment: Right this is what I did. Now running fine. Thanks for the help